# Sending data via wifi in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, wifi

How to send data via Wi-Fi in React Native app. Are there any package to do this?
I need to send data to an embedded device which has a Wi-Fi module.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure you can actually use this npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-p2p

You have to test it with real devices, but it's pretty simple to use it, just watch the documentation in the npm page.